# When I click the mouse how do I make it so the arrays re shuffle and have a different output?

Tags: processing

The goal of the project is to make a MadLib.  I want the array to shuffle each time the mouse is clicked, how would I go about doing that?

```
String madLib = "I went to #place# with #person#.  I know #person# from when we #event#.  At #place# we saw #thing#.  It was #adjective# so we ran away to #otherPlace#. ";
String[] array1 = {"Pakistan", "The Pentagon", "Universal Studios Sound Stage No. 5", "The basement of the United States Embassy in Iran", "Uncle Randy's Attic"};
String[] array2 = {"Former President Bill Clinton", "Ten Dolla Founding Fatha Alexander Hamilton", "Former Bufffalo Bills Running Back Orenthal James 'OJ' Simpson ", "Clifford From Clifford The Big Red Dog", "Director and 2 time oscar winner Quentin Tarantino "};
String[] array3 = {"Stole the entire contents of Fort Knox", "Taught John D. Rockefeller how to get oil", "Tried to but failed to prevent the Cold War", "Tried to save Brandon Lee", "Attemted to rob a Boost Mobile and got locked in"};
String[] array4 = {"A taxidermied lion with three legs ", "cryogenically frozen Walt Disney", "A below average height but above average speed brown colored horse", "A bucket of warm cow milk", "A replica of political podcaster Ben Shapiro"};
String[] array5 = {"Barking", "Running around", "Eating the Travis Scott meal from McDonalds", "Watching Season 1 of Mickeymouse Clubhouse", "Verbally abusing a cardboard cutout of Air Buddy for the Air Bud movies"};
String[] array6 = {"A random house", "the museum of cats", "The dog adoption center", "The Wendys drivethrough line", "The window and light fixture store"};


void setup() {
 
} 
void draw(){
}
void mousePressed(){
   
 
  int index1 = int(random(array1.length));  
  int index2 = int(random(array2.length));  
  int index3 = int(random(array3.length));  
  int index4 = int(random(array4.length));  
  int index5 = int(random(array5.length));
  int index6 = int(random(array6.length));  
  

  madLib = madLib.replace("#place#", (array1[index1]));
  madLib = madLib.replace("#person#", (array2[index2]));
  madLib = madLib.replace("#event#", (array3[index3]));
  madLib = madLib.replace("#thing#", (array4[index4]));
  madLib = madLib.replace("#adjective#", (array5[index5]));
  madLib = madLib.replace("#otherPlace#", (array6[index6]));
  
  println(madLib);
}
```

Comment: So, how does the code you have shown not do what you want?  Isn't selecting a random index the same as shuffling the array and then choosing the first index?

Comment: right now each time I click the mouse the output is the same.  My goal is to make each mouse click produce a different version version of the output

Comment: Interesting.  How can the output be the same if you are doing a replace using a random index?

Comment: I am not sure.  I assume I need to make a new shuffle on each mouse click but I am not sure on how to do that.

Comment: thanks for the help but I found a way to do it, thanks!

Comment: No, I see what is going on.  The first time through madLib contains #place# and other placeholders.  What does it contain after the first mouseclick?  All the placeholders have been replaced!  So the second time around all the replace functions do nothing because the thing they would replace doesn't exist.  In the click function you need to make a copy of the string and then do the replace on the copy so that the original string is left along and can be used next time you click.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That's it! Something like `String madLibResult = madLib.replace("#place#", (array1[index1]));
  madLibResult = madLibResult.replace("#person#", (array2[index2]));
  madLibResult = madLibResult.replace("#event#", (array3[index3]));
  madLibResult = madLibResult.replace("#thing#", (array4[index4]));
  madLibResult = madLibResult.replace("#adjective#", (array5[index5]));
  madLibResult = madLibResult.replace("#otherPlace#", (array6[index6]));` should do it. You should post the answer

Answer (score 0):

What you have written in mousePressed modifies the original madLib string, replacing all the hash delimited parameters with new information.  That works fine the first time it is run and the string that is printed has those parameters replaced so you get the right output.

But now the madLib string doesn't contain any hash delimited parameters, so when mousePressed runs again none of the replace commands does anything because the hash delimited parameters they are replacing no longer exist.

So you need to modify a copy of the string and do your replacements on the copy and leave the original string alone.  Thanks to @GeorgeProfenza for this code sample:

```
String madLib = "I went to #place# with #person#.  I know #person# from when we #event#.  At #place# we saw #thing#.  It was #adjective# so we ran away to #otherPlace#. ";

String[] array1 = {"Pakistan", "The Pentagon", "Universal Studios Sound Stage No. 5", "The basement of the United States Embassy in Iran", "Uncle Randy's Attic"};
String[] array2 = {"Former President Bill Clinton", "Ten Dolla Founding Fatha Alexander Hamilton", "Former Bufffalo Bills Running Back Orenthal James 'OJ' Simpson ", "Clifford From Clifford The Big Red Dog", "Director and 2 time oscar winner Quentin Tarantino "};
String[] array3 = {"Stole the entire contents of Fort Knox", "Taught John D. Rockefeller how to get oil", "Tried to but failed to prevent the Cold War", "Tried to save Brandon Lee", "Attemted to rob a Boost Mobile and got locked in"};
String[] array4 = {"A taxidermied lion with three legs ", "cryogenically frozen Walt Disney", "A below average height but above average speed brown colored horse", "A bucket of warm cow milk", "A replica of political podcaster Ben Shapiro"};
String[] array5 = {"Barking", "Running around", "Eating the Travis Scott meal from McDonalds", "Watching Season 1 of Mickeymouse Clubhouse", "Verbally abusing a cardboard cutout of Air Buddy for the Air Bud movies"};
String[] array6 = {"A random house", "the museum of cats", "The dog adoption center", "The Wendys drivethrough line", "The window and light fixture store"};

void setup() {
}
void draw() {
}
void mousePressed() {
  int index1 = int(random(array1.length));  
  int index2 = int(random(array2.length));  
  int index3 = int(random(array3.length));  
  int index4 = int(random(array4.length));  
  int index5 = int(random(array5.length));
  int index6 = int(random(array6.length));  

  String madLibResult = madLib.replace("#place#",      (array1[index1]));
  madLibResult  = madLibResult.replace("#person#",     (array2[index2]));   
  madLibResult  = madLibResult.replace("#event#",      (array3[index3]));
  madLibResult  = madLibResult.replace("#thing#",      (array4[index4]));   
  madLibResult  = madLibResult.replace("#adjective#",  (array5[index5]));
  madLibResult  = madLibResult.replace("#otherPlace#", (array6[index6]));

  println(madLibResult);
}
```